# Find unique and biggest string values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array in the following format:

```
var jObj = [
{text:'use'},
{text: 'user'},
{text: 'users'},
{text: 'sec'},
{text: 'secu'},
{text: 'secur'},
{text: 'for'},
{text: 'form'}
]
```

i need a function which returns an array like:

```
[
{text: 'users'},
{text: 'secur'},
{text: 'form'}
]
```

i found some solutions here but they all return unique value, i want to have the unique longest string of the similar pattern.

any help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

**Edit**

i have tried the following code

```
var arr2 = []
$.each(jObj, function (index, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value.text, arr2) === -1 ) {
        arr2.push(value.text);
    }
});
```

this is giving me only the unique values, i am thinking of using indexOf, but not sure where to use?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: "_i need a function_" Well, did you try making one? You should post the code you have to achieve this and explain what isn't working about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a way to remove strings that are prefixes of other strings. The remaining strings will be naturally longest of their "kind".

A straightforward quadratic-time solution might be like this:

```js
var jObj = [
{text:'use'},
{text: 'user'},
{text: 'users'},
{text: 'sec'},
{text: 'secu'},
{text: 'secur'},
{text: 'for'},
{text: 'form'}
];

result = jObj.filter(function(a) {
   return jObj.every(function(b) {
      return a.text == b.text || b.text.indexOf(a.text) < 0;
   });
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,3));
```

If your array is really big (>1000 items), a more efficient method would be to build a prefix tree and walk it as "deep" as possible: see examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31635514/989121).

If your input is always sorted, a linear solution would be to iterate it and remove every element which is a prefix of the next one:

```
result = jObj.filter(function(item, n, self) {
    return !self[n + 1] || self[n + 1].text.indexOf(item.text) < 0;
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot @georg, within seconds of me asking the question got downvoted!

Comment: @Vikram: you're welcome, next time phrase your question wisely, so that it doesn't sound like "gimme codez".

Answer (score 2):

A nonquadratic/linear time version:

```js
var jObj = [
    { text: 'use' },
    { text: 'user' },
    { text: 'users' },
    { text: 'sec' },
    { text: 'secu' },
    { text: 'secur' },
    { text: 'for' },
    { text: 'form' },
    { text: 'use'},
    { text: 'abc'},
    { text: '1abc'},
    { text: 'abc1'},
    { text: 'abc2'},
    { text: 'abcd'},
    { text: 'abc'}
];

var result = jObj.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r.some(function (b, i) { return ~a.text.indexOf(b.text) && (r[i] = a); }) ||
    r.some(function (b) { return ~b.text.indexOf(a.text); }) ||
    r.push(a);
    return r;
}, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This is clever, but doesn't seem to work right with unsorted input, as in `[{ text: 'users' }, { text: 'user' }, { text: 'use' }]`

Comment: @georg, now it works.